# Can Locust test a system that uses the CORBA IIOP protocol

Tags: corba, locust, iiop

The phrase “almost any system or protocol” in the Locust Features/• Can test any system, leaves me with uncertainty and doesn’t define what that really means.   As a developer my first question when reading this is to wonder if it can test a system that uses the CORBA IIOP protocol, which is almost unknown in 2021.  I’m sure Locust can handle HTTP/HTTPS with HTML, XML, and JSON payloads, But does it handle CORBA IIOP protocol?

Answer (score 2):

Locust can test any system, it just won't support every system with the built-in clients. What you'd have to do is write your own code to send requests to your system and then manually fire off Locust reporting events at the appropriate times. But you can then use Locust to distribute and orchestrate the load for you. Check out this part of the Locust docs:

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/testing-other-systems.html

You can even find Locust runners written in other languages such as Go ([boomer](https://github.com/myzhan/boomer)) and Java ([Locust4j](https://github.com/myzhan/locust4j)) in case Python isn't the best fit for the code you need to run.